# android studio root and dependencies errors

Tags: java

A problem occurred configuring root project 'Android-Radio'.

> Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':classpath'.
>   Could not download lombok-ast.jar (com.android.tools.external.lombok:lombok-ast:0.2.3): No cached version available for offline mode

Comment: Turn off offline mode in intellij

Answer (score 0):

**For Intellij IDEA:**

Hit `Ctrl+Shift+P` in your keyboard and search for `gradle offline` and select `Toggle gradle offline mode`

It'll shift you to online mode and for first build it may take some time to fetch latest version of dependencies.